# no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer serializable hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a rails API. I have an issue with the JSONAPI serializer I'm using where i keep getting the same error when trying to access the data attributes:

> "exception": "#<TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer>",

This is my apartments controller method that gives the error:

```
  def index
    @appartments = Appartment.all
    render json: AppartmentSerializer.new(@appartments).serializable_hash[:data][:attributes]
  end
```

I don't get the error when I remove :attributes but then I also get the attributes in the JSON object.

This is the object I want to return (but gives me errors):

```
[
  {
   ...
  },
  {
    ...
  },...

]
```

This is the object I can currently return when I remove the attributes value from the serializable hash:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "appartment",
    "attributes": {
      ...
    }
  },

  {
    "id": "2",
    "type": "appartment",
    "attributes": {
      ...
    }
  },...

]
```

Comment: The whole point of using the JSONAPI serializer is to provide responses that adhere to the spec... while you could extract the desired JSON by looping over the serialization result its pretty silly.

Comment: The gem you are using, implementing jsonapi standards, altering its behaviour like this probably will cause future problem (including other tables records in 1 response for example) if you want a simple serialized json response you can try another gems for example blueprinter